# Delphi Community Edition Install Errors: Git and Mercurial executables not found

Tags: git, delphi

I have just installed Delphi Community Edition 10.3. I get the errors Git executable not found and Mercurial executable not found. I uninstalled and reinstalled Delphi CE but get the same errors. Can anyone help me in resolving these issues? I am new to Delphi. Also can anyone point me to a Delphi developer who does paid per incident tech support.

Comment: Are these tools supposed to ship with Delphi? Afaik, you have to install them yourself...

Comment: Your last q is offtopic here. You can check my profile for other Delphi communities where you can ask such kind of questions!

Comment: Even if they are installed, you have to enter the path to each by yourself. There is no automated search.

Comment: Installation issues should be addressed to Embarcadero support. They provide free support for installation problems across all Delphi versions. And asking for a *developer who does paid per incident tech support* is an inappropriate question for this site. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.